# HTML formatting using bash

Tags: html, bash, shell

I've written a simple bash script that reads Chef roles & databag's values creates a HTML report. HTML report is getting generated but there is a mismatch in the format to that of my expectation

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "<html><body><h1>Environment Details</h1>"
echo "<table border=1 width=700>"

while read environment
do

echo "<tr><th>Environment</th><th>Roles</th><th>Details</th></tr>"
echo "<tr> <td>$environment</td>"

knife data bag show $environment -F text > /home/user1/"$environment"comps.txt

while read comp
do
echo "<td>$comp</td>"

check1=`echo $comp |awk -F "_" ' {print NF} ' `

if [ "$check1" == "red" ]
  then
  knife data bag show $environment $comp -F text > /home/user1/"$environment"details.txt
  comp_name=`echo $comp | cut -d '-' -f2 |cut -d '_' -f2`
  id=`echo $comp | cut -d '_' -f5`
  Server_IP=`echo $comp | cut -d '_' -f1,2,3,4`
  Environment_name=`echo $environment | sed -e 's/_deployment//g'`

  echo "<td><pre>comp: $comp_name"
  echo "Instance: $id"
  echo "Environment: $Environment_name"

 Deployed_Build=`grep "comp_build:" /home/user1/"$environment"details.txt | cut -d ' ' -f2`

if [ "$comp_name" == "dagger" ]
then
  JBoss_version="Not Available"
  JRE_version="Not Available"
  JVM_Argument="Not Available"
  Debug_Port="Not Available"
else
  JBoss_version=`grep "jboss:" /home/user1/"$environment"details.txt | cut -d ' ' -f12`
  JRE_version=`grep "jre:" /home/user1/"$environment"details.txt | cut -d ' ' -f14`
  JVM_Argument=`grep "jvm_argument:" /home/user1/"$environment"details.txt | sed -e 's/jvm_argument:    //g'`
  Port_check=`echo $JVM_Argument | tr -s " " "\n" | grep -w address | wc -l`

 if [ "$Port_check" == "aa" ]
 then
  Debug_Port=`echo $JVM_Argument | tr -s " " "\n" | grep -w address | cut -d ',' -f3 | cut -d '=' -f2`
 else
  Debug_Port="NA"
 fi
fi
echo "Port: $Debug_Port"
echo "Deployed Build: $Deployed_Build"
echo "JBoss version: $JBoss_version"
echo "jre: $JRE_version"
echo "JVM args: $JVM_Argument</pre></td></tr>"

fi

done </home/user1/"$environment"comps.txt

done </home/user1/environments.txt

echo "</table>"
echo "</body></html>"
```

I went thru some basics of HTML from W3schools and tried other options too but I'm unable to crack it. Thanks in advance for any help here !!

**Current Output I'm getting**

```html
<html><body><h1>Environment Details</h1>
<table border=1 width=700>
<tr><th>Environment</th><th>Roles</th><th>Details</th></tr>
<tr> <td>Prod</td>
<td><pre>Component: Marvelservlets
Instance: instance-7
Environment: Prod
Port: Not Enabled
Deployed Build: Marvelservlets-3388_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue-3388_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue
JBoss version: 5.1.0
jre: 1.6.0_24
JVM args: -MarvelOBRAND_MIGRATED=true -DAS_VERSION=5.0 -MarvelOM.org.FEATURE_NEW_dagger_KEY=true -DSUPPORT_BCT_MESSAGING=true -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.access -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.password -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1390 -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Marvelom.org.reset.management.enabled=true -Marvelom.org.rest.test_mode=true -Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</pre></td></tr>
<td><pre>Component: Marvel
Instance: instance-8
Environment: Prod
Port: 7105
Deployed Build: Marvel-3388_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue-3388_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue
JBoss version: 5.1.0
jre: 1.6.0_24
JVM args: -MarvelOBRAND_MIGRATED=true -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver=true -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl -DAS_VERSION=5.0 -Xms768m -Xmx2048m -MarvelOM.org.CATEGORIZATION.MERCHANT_NAME_START=1 -MarvelOM.org.FEATURE_NEW_dagger_KEY=true -DSUPPORT_BCT_MESSAGING=true -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.access -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.password -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1291 -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Marvelom.org.Marvel.startupargs=cacheserver,dbfiler,paymentengine,bpaaengine,statsengine -Marvelom.org.payitall.cache.load=false -Marvelom.org.reset.management.enabled=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7105,suspend=n</pre></td></tr>
<td><pre>Component: paymentengine
Instance: instance-5
Environment: Prod
Port: 7113
Deployed Build: paymentengine-142_00_build_nprlegacy-release_releasevalue-142_00_build_nprlegacy-release_releasevalue
JBoss version: 5.1.0
jre: 1.6.0_24
JVM args: -Marvelom.org.config.instance.id=5 -Marvelom.org.config.machine.id=192.168.112.164 -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7113,suspend=n -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms768m -Xmx2048m -DAS_VERSION=5.0 -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.access -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/user/jre1.6.0_24_x64/lib/management/jmxremote.password -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=2299 -Marvelom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Marvelom.org.reset.management.enabled=true -Xloggc:/var/log/org/jvm_CORE_5.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc -server -Dapp.name=PFM -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Marvelom.org.appmode=INPROC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -DAS_VERSION=5.0 -XX:NewRatio=5 -MarvelOMPONENT_NAME=paymentengine -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.home.dir=/opt/sdp/jboss-5.1.0/server/instance-5 -Dotc.component.name=paymentengin</pre></td></tr>
<td><pre>Component: central
Instance: instance-15
Environment: Prod
Port: 7115
Deployed Build: central-3306_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue-3306_00_build_oldrelease-release_releasevalue
JBoss version: 5.1.0
jre: 1.6.0_24
JVM args: -MarvelOBRAND_MIGRATED=true -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=7115,suspend=n -DAS_VERSION=5.0 -MarvelOM.org.FEATURE_NEW_dagger_KEY=true -Marvelom.org.util.logging.syslog_logging.enable=false -MarvelOMPONENT_NAME=central -DDEVELOPER_jio_SECURED_ENABLED=true -Marvelom.org.rest.test_mode=true -Marvelom.org.saml.keystore.password=changeit -Xms1536m -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Marvelom.org.finapp.resiliency.switch=1 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhealthcheck.enable=true -Dhtml.jio.published.location=/opt/ctier/node/finapp -Dhtml.jio.uncertified.location=/opt/ctier/node/finapp -Dhtml.jio.certified.location=/opt/ctier/node/finapp -javaagent:/opt/newrelic_Java/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.app_name="QA_Frontend_Java" -Marvelontrast.level=DEBUG -javaagent:/opt/ctier/contrast.jar -Marvelontrast.override.appversion=MCRBC</pre></td></tr>
<td><pre>Component: dapdagger
Instance: instance-1
Environment: Prod
Port: Not Available
Deployed Build: dapdagger-33__shelvedbuild_platform-fleming_release-33__shelvedbuild_platform-fleming_release
JBoss version: Not Available
jre: Not Available
JVM args: Not Available</pre></td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

**Expected Output**

```html
<html>
<body>
<table border=1 width=400>
<tr>
<th>Environment</th>
<th>Chef Roles</th>
<th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prod</td>
<td>Role_43</td>
<td>jvm value:1.9<br>mx zize:100<br>version:7.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Role_32</td>
<td>jvm value:1.7<br>mx zize:34<br>version:7.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Role_1</td>
<td>jvm value:1.7<br>mx zize:124<br>version:8.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>QA</td>
<td>QA_based_Role</td>
<td>jvm value:1.8<br>mx zize:84<br>version:4.8.0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Test_Role</td>
<td>jvm value:1.6<br>mx zize:844<br>version:9.98.0</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post an example of the HTML output and expected output? You can use the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but maybe it'd be time to switch to a better programming language like Python for this task? I understand if that's not an option, of course.

Comment: Add the code example

Comment: @mplungjan : Thank you for your time, I have edited my question and added the HTML output I got, hope I have done it right

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. : I have added the snippet of my outcome, thanks

Comment: @AKX: you're very much right but I would like to complete this in bash at this moment at least :)

Comment: Try removing <pre> in bash

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR.: Didn't help :( and it gave a different format altogether. I'm unable to edit my question now

Comment: @mplungjan : Added both - Current output's as well as expected outputs snippets. Thank you.

Comment: Forgve me for being pedantic, but `echo "<html><body><h1>Environment Details</h1>"` in your code isn't going to put those tags on separate lines as you show in the expected output. You didn't ask for embedded newlines. Can you be clearer on what the differences you wanted and didn't want are?

Comment: The answer is given by finished???

Comment: I don't have a way to test now, but my recollection is that nested `while read ..` loops are problematic, and require using numbered input streams after the first `done < inputFile`. Unfortunately, there is no standard terminology for numbered input streams (if you search for that here, you won't find anything), but I mean things like `2<&1` (but don't remember the exact syntax you'll need, and I'm away from my normal working environment). Good luck.

Comment: Am I reading it right that you're assuming that `echo "<td><pre> [..]"` will NOT include `<pre>` in the output? Bash doesn't know about HTML and will not try to reformat `pre` tags into tables.

Comment: 1) 1 echo == 1 line.  If you put many HTML tags in the same echo, they will end up on the same line.  2) indentation would do great on your code.  It might be an SO formatting issue, but you want to use it.  Ex. the second while is in the first while but it is indented the same.  3) as @thatotherguy mentionned, if you echo "<pre>", you will get "<pre>" in your HTML.  4) for bash, HTML is just text.  You can get a bash script to output HTML, but **you** must take care of all the formatting.  Bash will just output it has is.

Comment: And your samples in the question do not match.  Ex. in the current output you have  a bunch of text after `<td>Prod</td>` that is not found in the desired output.  Your script must take care of filtering what you want or not, it will do nothing automatically or implicitly.

Comment: Another point, in Bash if you put echo, it will automatically add the carriage return, and you will see the next output on the next line.  In HTML, you will also see that carriage return.  But in the browser, it will not be showed.  Carriage return does not mean anything in HTML.  If you provide a *small* sample of your input txt files, we could provide you with a script demo for what you want.